# Connection to Wireless Router from Windows XP

Tags: windows-xp, router, wireless-router

I have a Windows XP PC, a Windows 7 Laptop and a wireless router ( [Rosewill RNX-EasyN4](http://www.rosewill.com/products/1281/ProductDetail_Overview.htm)). I put an additional PCI Ethernet card into my PC, so it now has two network ports (the first being the built-in motherboard Ethernet port). I am trying to do something like:

[PC] <---- Ethernet ----> [Modem WAN] <---- Wireless ---> [Laptop]

I am not good at networking so I might be missing something obvious here. I am trying to figure out if I need to use DHCP (Obtain IP Address automatically) or specify the IP Address on the PC. Also should I specify a static IP for the modems WAN port? (I think I can do this in the configuration.)

**Note:** No internet connection in my attempt above. The built-in Ethernet port of the PC is unused.

The following is what I have tried so far: 
    I first tried to verify if the new PCI Ethernet card is working. I took off the internet connection to the PCI from its regular built-in Ethernet port and put the cable into this new port. The PC had internet.

I tried to establish a wired connection between the PC and the Laptop. For this I set both the PC and the Laptop to static IPs and connected them using a crossover cable. This worked.

So if I need to connect to my wireless router from my PC should I set it to DHCP or a static IP? Also what do I need to configure my WAN port, i.e. DHCP or static IP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your WAN port needs to be set to DHCP so that your router can obtain an IP address from your Internet service provider. Unless your ISP is providing you with a static IP address, their servers will most likely ignore your router unless it goes through their DHCP server first.

It's easiest just to set your computers to DHCP, and the router's LAN/WiFi to serve DHCP as well. If for some reason you're having trouble connecting to your router, temporarily set a static IP address on one of your computers that's in the default range of your router (something like 192.168.1.10, stay out of the default DHCP range which is probably above .100) then reconfigure the router to DHCP.

If everything is set to DHCP all around, it should be pretty much plug and play.

**Edit:** I thought by no internet connection you meant it wouldn't work. If you just want to connect these devices then don't use the WAN port at all, it's meant for Internet connections. Enable DHCP for the router's clients, plug the PC in to a LAN port, and connect the laptop to the wireless. Make sure that AP isolation is turned off (if it's even there on your router) and set both machines to DHCP.

Comment: There is no internet connection in my attempt above just one PC, a Router and a Laptop. I have put this in bold in my original post. How do I make a connection between just these three devices. Thank you.

Comment: @O.O. Not sure if edits show up in your inbox, but I updated my answer.

Comment: Sorry **@r.tanner.f** for the delay. Your suggestion in the **“edit”** section of your Answer above worked perfectly for me. I am sorry I could not confirm this or try this out earlier. Thanks again.

Comment: Right on glad it worked.